# Parsing JSON-String fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I read the content of a `<script>` - area a a STRING.

```
$('script').each(function() {
        if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("AF_initDataCallback({key: '12'")>-1) {
            var complete=this.innerHTML;
            var startJSON=complete.indexOf('[');
            var endJSON=complete.lastIndexOf(']');
        //    var ar=eval(complete.substring(startJSON,endJSON));
            var ar2=$.parseJSON(complete.substring(startJSON,endJSON));

        }
    });
```

Through manipulations I receive the following content I want to conver to a "real" JSON

```
"[[[["23e29db10f09d296"]
,["Friends",,"Your real friends, the ones you feel comfortable sharing private details with.",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000000",1,1,1]
]
,[["3d5354de09baf36e"]
,["Family",,"Your close and extended family, with as many or as few in-laws as you want.",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000001",2,1,1]
]
,[["21f948f108db184f"]
,["Techie",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000002",0,1,1]
]
,[["7373617e08bbeac4"]
,["funny",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000003",0,1,1]
]
,[["4ace516d8d62f107"]
,["Job",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000004",0,1,1]
]
,[["5594b1f8d1f1e37"]
,["Followers",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000005",0,1,1]
]
,[["2bc5e6a50e948a73"]
,["Job: Nice",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000006",0,1,1]
]
,[["397a6a970cade6e8"]
,["rx8",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000007",0,1,1]
]
,[["13ea3c80821ad9c"]
,["promi",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000008",0,1,1]
]
,[["588da2260e942271"]
,["Firmen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000009",0,1,1]
]
,[["337bb5990e4870e5"]
,["News",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000a",0,1,1]
]
,[["4856572c0e1de220"]
,["Gaming",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000b",0,1,1]
]
,[["3555f8f8bc5726f"]
,["mine",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000c",0,1,1]
]
,[["6a01451c89ca64ae"]
,["Nette Leute",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000d",0,1,1]
]
,[["90ed4e98f5820f7"]
,["Hamburg",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000e",0,1,1]
]
,[["56bac85c894170b8"]
,["Job-Contacts",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000f",0,1,1]
]
,[["485ab93e8e81d66d"]
,["Fussball",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000010",0,1,1]
]
,[["5ec1bb9409bad931"]
,["Journaille",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000011",0,1,1]
]
,[["135ce0d189b1e545"]
,["mal schauen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000012",,1,1]
]
,[["1ecbecf28ec85202"]
,["Lonely Circle",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000013",0,1,1]
]
,[["38a246348c513a39"]
,["ignore",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000014",0,1,1]
]
,[["2f9c4a3c0e1f43b9"]
,["Vielschreiber",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000015",0,1,1]
]
,[["7fd0532089537115"]
,["Bombenbauer",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000016",0,1,1]
]
,[["765e2a78e64b1a6"]
,["Techsites",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000017",0,1,1]
]
,[["598e823988cf077e"]
,["OK",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000018",0,1,1]
]
,[["3edae58f895c3933"]
,["Star Trek",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000019",0,1,1]
]
,[["22ad725f89342264"]
,["Deppen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001a",0,1,1]
]
,[["254c1dec0d1bf02a"]
,["science",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001b",0,1,1]
]
,[["2b4588aa898848a4"]
,["Undeutsch",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001c",0,1,1]
]
,[["300a8672084d875b"]
,["eurpeans",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001d",0,1,1]
]
,[["7de54f780f74eb6d"]
,["Autoren",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001e",0,1,1]
]
,[["152f86d208909412"]
,["Unterhaltung",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001f",0,0,1]
]
,[["6d96794b0f6ac25e"]
,["Bookmarks",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000020",0,1,1]
]
,[["76c46c5489053a6b"]
,["Usertreffen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000021",0,1,1]
]
,[["80d2af10e3778b1"]
,["g+j",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000022",0,1,1]
]
,[["e2e37408d864f3f"]
,["Ouya Follower",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000023",0,1,1]
]
,[["2916afdf8cbcf8e0"]
,["Ingress DE",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000024",0,1,1]
]
,[["74bca48bb5e9bf"]
,["Ouya",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000025",0,1,1]
]
,[["63d74040084991b1"]
,["Spam",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000026",0,1,1]
]
,[["6d0e7cf08bee08d8"]
,["Geeks",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000027",0,1,1]
]
,[["1deb550f8d794be4"]
,["janzneu",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000028",0,0,1]
]
,[["6c02104c094dd570"]
,["urlaub",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000029",0,0,1]
]
,[["267736b60f3a46e7"]
,["Heimat",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002a",0,1,1]
]
,[["7a7fd8738eedd564"]
,["Google",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002b",0,0,1]
]
,[["3e6492e98907eda2"]
,["Politik",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002c",0,0,1]
]
,[["42f28c228ae071ac"]
,["prio",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002d",0,0,1]
]
,[["2c2fbd540de7df0f"]
,["Optimizer",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002e",0,1,1]
]
]
"
```

So I receive a STRING that already "looks" like JSON and "was" a real JSON before.

But when I try to convert this to a real object using `$.parseJSON` I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Do I have to do some conversions before or wrap something around it?

(Update) The FULL script-area I want to grab:

```
<script>AF_initDataCallback({key: '12', isError:  false , data:[[[["23e29db10f09d296"]
,["Friends",,"Your real friends, the ones you feel comfortable sharing private details with.",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000000",1,1,1]
]
,[["3d5354de09baf36e"]
,["Family",,"Your close and extended family, with as many or as few in-laws as you want.",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000001",2,1,1]
]
,[["21f948f108db184f"]
,["Techie",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000002",0,1,1]
]
,[["7373617e08bbeac4"]
,["funny",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000003",0,1,1]
]
,[["4ace516d8d62f107"]
,["Job",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000004",0,1,1]
]
,[["5594b1f8d1f1e37"]
,["Followers",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000005",0,1,1]
]
,[["2bc5e6a50e948a73"]
,["Job: Nice",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000006",0,1,1]
]
,[["397a6a970cade6e8"]
,["rx8",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000007",0,1,1]
]
,[["13ea3c80821ad9c"]
,["promi",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000008",0,1,1]
]
,[["588da2260e942271"]
,["Firmen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000009",0,1,1]
]
,[["337bb5990e4870e5"]
,["News",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000a",0,1,1]
]
,[["4856572c0e1de220"]
,["Gaming",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000b",0,1,1]
]
,[["3555f8f8bc5726f"]
,["mine",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000c",0,1,1]
]
,[["6a01451c89ca64ae"]
,["Nette Leute",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000d",0,1,1]
]
,[["90ed4e98f5820f7"]
,["Hamburg",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000e",0,1,1]
]
,[["56bac85c894170b8"]
,["Job-Contacts",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000f",0,1,1]
]
,[["485ab93e8e81d66d"]
,["Fussball",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000010",0,1,1]
]
,[["5ec1bb9409bad931"]
,["Journaille",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000011",0,1,1]
]
,[["135ce0d189b1e545"]
,["mal schauen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000012",,1,1]
]
,[["1ecbecf28ec85202"]
,["Lonely Circle",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000013",0,1,1]
]
,[["38a246348c513a39"]
,["ignore",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000014",0,1,1]
]
,[["2f9c4a3c0e1f43b9"]
,["Vielschreiber",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000015",0,1,1]
]
,[["7fd0532089537115"]
,["Bombenbauer",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000016",0,1,1]
]
,[["765e2a78e64b1a6"]
,["Techsites",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000017",0,1,1]
]
,[["598e823988cf077e"]
,["OK",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000018",0,1,1]
]
,[["3edae58f895c3933"]
,["Star Trek",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000019",0,1,1]
]
,[["22ad725f89342264"]
,["Deppen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001a",0,1,1]
]
,[["254c1dec0d1bf02a"]
,["science",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001b",0,1,1]
]
,[["2b4588aa898848a4"]
,["Undeutsch",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001c",0,1,1]
]
,[["300a8672084d875b"]
,["eurpeans",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001d",0,1,1]
]
,[["7de54f780f74eb6d"]
,["Autoren",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001e",0,1,1]
]
,[["152f86d208909412"]
,["Unterhaltung",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000001f",0,0,1]
]
,[["6d96794b0f6ac25e"]
,["Bookmarks",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000020",0,1,1]
]
,[["76c46c5489053a6b"]
,["Usertreffen",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000021",0,1,1]
]
,[["80d2af10e3778b1"]
,["g+j",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000022",0,1,1]
]
,[["e2e37408d864f3f"]
,["Ouya Follower",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000023",0,1,1]
]
,[["2916afdf8cbcf8e0"]
,["Ingress DE",,"",,,,,,,2,2,,"00000024",0,1,1]
]
,[["74bca48bb5e9bf"]
,["Ouya",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000025",0,1,1]
]
,[["63d74040084991b1"]
,["Spam",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000026",0,1,1]
]
,[["6d0e7cf08bee08d8"]
,["Geeks",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000027",0,1,1]
]
,[["1deb550f8d794be4"]
,["janzneu",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000028",0,0,1]
]
,[["6c02104c094dd570"]
,["urlaub",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"00000029",0,0,1]
]
,[["267736b60f3a46e7"]
,["Heimat",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002a",0,1,1]
]
,[["7a7fd8738eedd564"]
,["Google",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002b",0,0,1]
]
,[["3e6492e98907eda2"]
,["Politik",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002c",0,0,1]
]
,[["42f28c228ae071ac"]
,["prio",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002d",0,0,1]
]
,[["2c2fbd540de7df0f"]
,["Optimizer",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000002e",0,1,1]
]
]
]
});</script>
```

Comment: given example isn't valid json. Please copy full string text

Comment: @VasilVanchuk I posted the full string text. As you can see it looks just like my posted part before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every index in an array must have a value. You can't have `[ something, , something ]`

You probably want a `null` between each pair of adjacent commas.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, empty array members are not valid, for example:

```
["News",,,,,,,,,2,2,,"0000000a",0,1,1]
```

If you get rid of these, it could be valid JSON:

```
["News",2,2,"0000000a",0,1,1]
```

Actually, this is what the error message tells you :). You should read the [JSON spec](http://json.org/), it is really short. Could also run a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Following the answers from @Quentin and @kapa I came to the following solution:

```
var cstr=complete.substring(startJSON,endJSON+1);
while (cstr.indexOf(",,")>0) {
   cstr=cstr.replace(",,",",null,")                
};
var ar2=$.parseJSON(cstr);
```

To be honest I don't like it. It looks to dirty to me.

Comment: The clean way would be to fix the original JSON to be, well, JSON. But I understand you might not have access to that. So all you can do is hacks like this.